# Traps and pitfalls in elementary algebraic manipulation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, fake-proofs

Given the equation $x=x+2$:
\begin{align}
x &=x+2 \\\\
x-x &=2 \\\\
0&=2
\end{align}

This impies there is no solution

Given the equation $x+1=0$:
\begin{align}
x + 1 &=0 \\\\
\frac{x+1}{x+1} &= \frac{0}{x+1}  \\\\
1&=0
\end{align}
Clearly, the conclusion that there is no solution is invalid.
Is there a set of algebraic manipulation dos and don'ts to avoid such errors?

Comment: There was nothing wrong with the manipulation in the first case.  The initial equation, $x=x+2$, was already impossible.  For the second, don't divide by $0$.

Comment: The equation $x=x+2$ over a field is equivalent to $2=0$, which is true for all fields of characteristic two, e.g., in $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$, but false otherwise.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I'm not criticising you or anything, but I don't think a response using group theory is very helpful for the OP. The OP did specifically mention "elementary". But whatever, you've been here longer than me so you probably know better :)

Comment: @Ajay Yes, I know. This is meant as a perspective, not as a practical answer. I find it important to realise that an equation is not just an equation, but depends on in which domain (or field, or whatever) you consider the equation.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I understand where you're coming from, but what's the point? I seriously doubt the OP even knows what a field is. I think what would have been better was for you to add some more explanation. Maybe a link or video explaining what fields are and what characteristic 2 means with some accompanying explanation. That would definitely have helped the OP see your perspective.

Comment: @Ajay The OP may not know what a field is, but that $2=0$ is possible, he/she may have heard already from computer science, or from odd plus odd is even. Why not point to it? What is the point not to do it? If the OP doesn't like it, he/she can simply ignore it. But perhaps the OP will be curious about it, why not? Then the OP can still search for a video.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Fair point.

Comment: @DietrichBurde How is there any finite solution to $x=x+2\iff 0=2\iff$false? It looks like this field is defined to be a solution to the equation when there seemingly cannot be one.

Comment: @TymaGaidash  What do you mean by "seemingly cannot be"? Of course $2=0$ is true in $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$. Then $0$ corresponds to even numbers, and $1$ to odd numbers. Clear $2=1+1=0$, because "odd plus odd is even". Some people write $2\equiv 0\bmod 2$, but in the field $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$ this means the equality $2=0$. You are doing so advanced integrals, so that you certainly know this first semester material.

Comment: @DietrichBurde By “seemingly cannot be true”, it was assumed the set of real numbers solved $x=x+2$, so it was confusing how a field could solve the equation. However, after a search, $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$ relates to [modular arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic) which does allow this behavior.

Comment: @TymaGaidash Yes, this is what I meant. Our students learn this modular arithmetic much earlier than elliptic integrals of the second kind, for example. So I was surprised.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First case:

You write:

> $x=x+2 \rightarrow  x-x=2$

Algebraically, you added $-x$ to both sides. The operation is correct. However, the starting point was not correct. I mean what does $x=x+2$ tell us? It says that there is a quantity equals itself plus 2. This statement is illogic. Hence, the problem is in applying the algebraic operation to an expression that is not logical. Such cases appear when proving some statements by supposing the opposite argument and proceed with algebraic operations to stop when such an illogic expression appears meaning that the assumption was false.

Second Case:

You write:

> $x+1 = 0$
>
> $\frac{x+1}{x+1} = \frac{0}{x+1} \rightarrow  1=0$

Division operation is undefined or illegal operation (well, maybe with one exception...see below) when you divide by explicit zero figure or an expression that is zero. This is the "defensive" approach to obtaining logical results that we were taught in school.  One way to see why this is so, when you consider the relationship between division and subtraction. For example, $\frac{6}{2}=3$ can be seen as the unique number of subtracting operations of $(6-2)$ until zero is reached. In case of division by zero, the number of operations is not unique it could be one, two, etc.

This restriction in division is adopted by all computer programming languages use (to my knowledge).

Violating this restriction could *possibly* lead to invalid expression, and performing operations on invalid expression leads to illogic results.

In cases, one may be interested in the value of the function $f(x)$ when the value very near, but not equal, zero. In such cases, we use the limit techniques.

You can read more about this here: [Wiki-Division By Zero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_by_zero).

I am aware of one case (very famous) where division by zero expression looks-like it works. This is the case of the Remainder Theorem. When you have a polynomial like $p(x)=x^2-1$ and you know that $x+1$ is a factor bit not the last factor of p(x), you can write $p(x)=\frac{x^2-1}{x+1}=x-1$. This is a valid case! It is not easy to see why this is valid without some knowledge in Analysis. For more on this you may want to look at [Introduction to Division by Zero Calculus](https://books.google.com.eg/books?id=BnkZEAAAQBAJ&pg=PA93&dq=factor%20theorem%20%22division%20by%20zero%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi2ldqNrq7-AhWGU6QEHaP9ApQQ6AF6BAgEEAI#v=onepage&q=factor%20theorem%20%22division%20by%20zero%22&f=false).